SharePoint File Handler - Preview is not working for SharePoint.... works fine with OneDrive
I'm using the File Handler interface  (in the app registration manifest, under "addIns" an entry with the  type of "fileHandler").
This works correctly with OneDrive, but with SharePoint, the "preview" option sends the user to a page that says "Hmm... Looks like we are unable to preview this file".   The other File Handler actions work correctly in SharePoint ("new", "open"... and it shows the file icon).

It is possible that the file type you are trying to preview is not supported by SharePoint. You can check the list of supported file types for SharePoint in the Microsoft documentation. Additionally, it is important to note that File Handler configurations are aggressively cached throughout the system for optimal performance, so it may take 24-48 hours for any configuration changes to take effect. If the issue persists, you can try clearing your browser cache and cookies.
References:
Adding custom preview, open, and actions to files with File Handlers 2.0

Thanks.  We've had our File Handler working for over a year.  All other aspects of the File Handler are working correctly.  We've cleared cache, and rebooted (familiar with the aggressive caching).   The file type is known (through the File Handler) because it's working for the "new" and the "open".  The file icon we've defined is also correctly showing.  It's only the preview feature that is not working.
